# MS Access - Load CustomUI Ribbon from VBA Add-in

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am developing a VBA add-in for MS Access. I have a CustomUI ribbon that loads fine when I open the add-in as a normal database. However, when I install the add-in using the Add-in manager, the custom ribbon does not appear.

My VBA add-in (.accda) currently consists of the following tables:

> `USysRegInfo` - Set up as described [on this page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/95174982-0b4f-46b6-ac80-ba6a4220d43a/workaround-for-microsoft-access-addin-bug?forum=accessdev#9771498f-d25b-4b6f-82b0-7e2e37d84db8)
>   `USysRibbons` - Set up as described [in this article (Customize the Ribbon - Access)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-the-ribbon-45e110b9-531c-46ed-ab3a-4e25bc9413de)

How do I configure the VBA add-in to show the CustomUI ribbon when the add-in is installed/loaded?

I have been able to find documentation so far only on how to create a VBA "Menu Add-in," and how to customize the ribbon for a normal database. I haven't found any documentation on using the CustomUI ribbon from a VBA add-in in MS Access, so maybe this isn't possible.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I am at the same point right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can reload the ribbon using

```
Application.LoadCustomUI NameOfTheRibbon, RibbonXMLFromUSysRibbonsTable
```

[More here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-loadcustomui-method-access)

Comment: I tried that, but it only loads the CustomUI ribbon into memory. It doesn't actually apply the ribbon. Additionally according to the documentation, it should only be used to load the `RibbonXml` manually if you don't have a `USysRibbons` table set up. (When the add-in is loaded, all ribbons specified in the `USysRibbons` table are automatically loaded into memory by Access, so `LoadCustomUI` is not necessary. The question is, how to apply one of the ribbons that's loaded into memory from an add-in).

Comment: See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd548010(v=office.12).aspx#Anchor_1) for details on how ribbons are loaded into memory for normal databases.

Comment: Where would you even call this from? The autoexec from the addin doesn't run when the addin is loaded by access.